# MonoTouch - Asynchronous UISearchBar

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I have an asynchronous UISearchBar setup as follows:

- Inherit UISearchDisplayDelegate & set it up for `myController.SearchDisplayController.Delegate`
- Override `ShouldReloadForSearchString` -> start a new thread calling a web service and return false to not reload the `UITableView`
- Web service completes in background -> call `BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`
- Reload tableview via `myController.SearchDisplayController.SearchResultsTableView.ReloadData()`

Everything works on the first search I make, I can backspace or type and see new results pop in asynchronously.

If I complete the search or cancel it, then try again, the call to ReloadData() causes the following crash:

```
2012-01-04 23:05:11.589 myApp[98047:2407] -[MainController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0ea840
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
  at MyApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/jonathanpeppers/Projects/MyApp/Main.cs:13
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
```

I don't dispose of anything, and am keeping all my delegates in member variables to prevent GC issues.  Every background thread seems to be calling `BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` properly as well.

Is this most likely a bug in MonoTouch?  If this is likely, I can create a repro.

Otherwise, let me know if I'm going about this wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a binding bug (I checked them to be sure). The data source should be set on the `UISearchDisplayController`, not on the table view (e.g. `SearchDisplayController.SearchResultsTableView`).

IOW replace:

```
        SearchDisplayController.SearchResultsTableView.Source = _tableSource;
```

with:

```
        SearchDisplayController.SearchResultsSource = _tableSource;
```

This will ensure the internal state of `UISearchDisplayController` is updated properly between uses.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered workaround:

- override `WillBeginSearch` in `UISearchDisplayDelegate`
- set `searchController.SearchResultsTableView.Source` to null
- when you have results to display, set `searchController.SearchResultsTableView.Source` to your table view source

Yet to hear if Xamarin thinks it's a bug or not.  I will post on the bug page as well.

Answer (score 0):

"unrecognized selector sent to instance" can also indicate that the object has been garbage collected to which you send the message, are you sure it still exists at the time of the reloadData call?

It happens to me sometimes when I create UI with code and create it inside loadView method and have the table view variable only on method scope, not the class scope.

Cure is simple, put the variable outside the method scope.

Comment: I'll play with it.  Which object would you think it is in my case, the UITableViewSource?  Right now I think I'm storing the UISearchDisplayDelegate and UITableViewSource in member variables, but I will check.  It is also strange that it happens on the second search every time, would the GC would be a little more random?

Comment: I am definitely saving those delegates, so they shouldn't be getting collected.  I'll make a repro and put it up somewhere.

Comment: Posted bug on Xamarin here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2746  I attached a repro, so you can download it to see my code.

Comment: I just ran the sample, and when I changed from BeginInvokeOnMainThread to InvokeOnMainThread all is fine.

my version of Monotouch is 5.0.4

Comment: Mine is still crashing when I gave that a try, still shouldn't matter, right?  BeginInvoke just let's the background thread continue on.  Try searching more, if it is the GC it might take 3 tries.